# Why does my javascript Catch block not execute?

Tags: javascript, exception

I feel silly asking this, I must be missing  something obvious.

My javascript looks as follows...

```
function onNewItemClick(event)
{
    alert('ello!');
    try
    {
        var xx = 111/0;
    }
    catch(exc)
    {
        alert('fff');
    }
}
```

alert('ello!') works like it should, but the alert('fff') in the Catch block never gets called. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The catch doesn't executes because division by zero doesn't rises an exception, it simply sets you `xx` variable to [`Infinity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Properties/Infinity).

To check if a number is finite you can use the [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/isFinite) function:

```
if (!isFinite(xx)) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Or to undefined depending on the browser.

Comment: Ha ha, that's what happens when a .NET junkie ventures into the javascript world :) Thanks!

Comment: @willem: You're welcome!, @jitter: That behavior is pretty much standard (see ECMA-262 Section *11.5.2*) http://is.gd/5clge (PDF)